# Observe multiple log files in one output

Tags: logs, tail

Is there an easy way to do something like `tail -f mylogfile` but to have the changes of more than one file displayed (maybe with the file name added as prefix to each line)? Or maybe a GUI tool? I am running Debian.

Comment: `multitail` is the king there. See [Combine input from multiple files/pipes without clobbering lines or blocking?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15521)

Comment: Thank you for that tip. This is a really helpful tool. It can also truncate files, clear the screen with one shortcut and so on.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Have you tried `tail -f file1 file2`? It appears to do exactly what you want, at least on my FreeBSD machine. Perhaps the `tail` that comes with a Debian system can do it too?

Comment: Yes. It works! Thank you. I'd never expected that it would be SO easy.

Comment: I usually use `-F` instead since a number of files may get truncated as I'm restarting server programs.

Comment: My new favorite parameter combo is `tail -qF *.log`: `-q` to hide the file names and `-F`, as Arcege pointed out, to let `tail` follow the name rather than the descriptor because my log files are being rotated.

Comment: Validated also on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: There is a limit to this. I have a folder with log files by PID for a worker that gets started for every new job in a queue (So lots of PIDs). If I `tail -f /var/log/folder/*` it returns the error "unable to execute /usr/bin/tail: Argument list too long"

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, answers along the lines of `tail -f file1 file2` wasn't quite what I had in mind.

I want to know what happened in several logs sort of most recently 'locally', regardless of the global chronological order.

To do that, I used something more like `watch -n1 tail -n10 file1 file2`

Answer (score 4):

For the exercise i wrote small node utility that does the same thing as tail -f f1 f2 f3

**Splex:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/splex

The main "upgrade" is that lines are color coded per file name, and that you can have table-like interface.

Another improvemtn, actually main reason I wrote this, is the ability to have **.splexrc.json** files in different folders, so instead having to type `tail -f f1 f2 f3`in one folder, then different files in other, you can write .splexrc.json file in root of your project and just type `splex` without file list arguments and it automatically stream relevant logs you enumerated in config file.